# Can you rename a process or object in BluePrism?

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I made a spelling error in the name of a Process
As processes cannot be deleted once they are run and the context menu that appears when you right click them does not offer the option to rename, is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 7):

You can go to the main page or initialize page in the case of objects, and double click on the box that is to the left of the start stage. The box looks something like that:

[image]

(Obviously the text will be different)

When this opens, you should see something like the below. Simply change the name, click on OK and save.

[image]

Comment: That is correct, just want to add it doesn't break any dependencies/schedulers after rename. When I did it first time, I was a bit worried, but it went well.

Answer (score -2):

Saving the whole process again (save as) is the only way I know of

Comment: That's what I did, but it does not remove the old one :(